# Css loading font: What does the # in a url mean and how to add a GET-parameter?

Tags: css, sass, webfonts

I'm using fontawesome with css/scss. The font is embeded in the scss like this:

```
src: url('#{$fa-font-path}/fa-regular-400.eot');
src: url('#{$fa-font-path}/fa-regular-400.eot?#iefix') format('embedded-opentype'),
url('#{$fa-font-path}/fa-regular-400.woff2') format('woff2'),
url('#{$fa-font-path}/fa-regular-400.woff') format('woff'),
url('#{$fa-font-path}/fa-regular-400.ttf') format('truetype'),
url('#{$fa-font-path}/fa-regular-400.svg#fontawesome') format('svg');
```

To make a preload run correctly on our server, I need to add a GET-parameter (this is due to session-things), so I need to change

```
fa-regular-400.woff2
```

to

```
fa-regular-400.woff2?preload
```

But what does the # do? In a "normal" URL on a webpage it would be the anchor, but in a font-file? How do I correctly add the preload-parameter to:

```
fa-regular-400.eot?#iefix
fa-regular-400.svg#fontawesome
```

Is it:

```
fa-regular-400.eot?#iefix&preload
fa-regular-400.svg#fontawesome?preload
```

or

```
fa-regular-400.eot?preload#iefix
fa-regular-400.svg?preload#fontawesome
```

??

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
fa-regular-400.eot?preload#iefix
fa-regular-400.svg?preload#fontawesome
```

this is the correct way. The `#part` is just a fragments and is usually entirely ignored when parsing HTTP requests. I even suspect most browsers don't even send it to the server.

You might want to double check `fa-regular-400.eot?preload#iefix` on older IE versions though (pre IE11), the entire reason for it in the first place is that their CSS parser ignores everything after the `?` which we abused to ignore other font formats.

For the SVG font, the `#id` is just there to tell the browser which svg element in the file to use as font.

Answer (score 0):

If the font is an OpenType collection, the fragment indicates which font from the collection to load.

If it's unspecified or unrecognised, it loads the first font from the collection ([ref](https://github.com/w3c/csswg-drafts/issues/2566))

If it's not an OpenType collection, it's ignored.